# markdown syntax validator

Tags: markdown, jekyll, octopress

Are there any specific rules for writing markdown when using Octopress(Jekyll)?

I've already tried pasting it to: http://markable.in/editor/ 
and it looks fine but when I use `rake preview` to generate the html from the markdown source it just generates a blank page.

This was the first block of code that cause the error in converting to html. I removed it and everything worked. But I don't know exactly why this block of code wouldn't work. Are there any plugins that I could install to make the interpreter(is that what's its called?) less sensitive. Or are there any tools out there that could point out to me what exactly is wrong with the source.

````
```
php artisan generate:migration create_departments_table department:string

php artisan generate:migration create_roles_table department_id:integer role:string

php artisan generate:migration create_transactions_table department_id:integer main_menu:string menu_text:string address:string

php artisan generate:migration create_rolestransactions_table role_id:integer transaction_id:integer status:integer

php artisan generate:migration create_userlogs_table user_id:integer user:string department:string transaction:string dateandtime:timestamp
```
````

Here's the source:
https://gist.github.com/4186168

Maybe you could point out to me what I'm doing wrong. Maybe you could point out a link to the rules to be followed for writing markdown that works perfectly with the interpreter.

**Update**

There is nothing on the html page that is generated. I've installed slash theme https://github.com/tommy351/Octopress-Theme-Slash

Here are the plugins that are installed:

[image]

I think most of them are default plugins because I don't remember having installed a plugin. And also if it might help, I'm on Windows.

Comment: I tried your post in my vanilla Octopress install and the page generates fine for me. Can you post the html?  Do you have any custom themes or plugins installed?

Comment: thanks for trying. I have installed the slash theme, I've edited my original post to include a screenshot to the plugins I have installed, please check it out

Comment: I'm new to octopress, so this may be an idiot question. Are you also running rake generate as well as rake preview? I have my install on my other box, so I can't check if I can replicate your results w/o running both.

Comment: I'm only running rake preview, rake generate converts markdown into html, rake preview does what rake generate does then serves the files at port 4000

Answer (score 1):

When I transform your code with the markdown executable, it works, but is interpreted wrong.

You shouldn't put blocks of code between triple backticks, just indent them with 4 spaces. The backticks are meant for inline code.

EDIT: I overlooked the backtick-block-code plugin. Above is rendered false.

Comment: so what do you think I would do?